# FTP client allowing more than 10 simultaneous uploads for Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, ftp

I am looking for a FTP client running on Microsoft Windows and with a GUI that allows more than 10 simultaneous uploads.

FileZilla is limited to 10:

[image]

WinSCP is limited to 9:

[image]

CyberDuck is limited to 9:

[image]

Any license and price is fine.

---

For example, in Linux CLI, I use `lftp`. [Explanation](https://superuser.com/a/726866/116475) from [wiak](https://superuser.com/users/89515/wiak):

> `lftp sftp://user:password@server.org:22 -e 'mirror --verbose
>   --use-pget-n=8 -c /remote/path /local/path'`
>
> - `sftp://` = uses SFTP protocol
> - `mirror` = mirror mode
> - `verbose` = shows the files being downloaded
> - `use-pget-n` = number of segments, realy useful to speed up big files
> - `parallel` = downloads multiplier files at the same time
>
> if you want to download files in parallel switch out `use-pget-n=8`
>   with `--parallel=8`

Comment: If you are trying to upload >10 times to the same site, you run the risk of being interpreted as a Denial Of Service attack.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes but sometimes I am uploading to my servers :-)

Comment: @Chenmunka: haha, reminds me of my old hoster who dropped more than one (!) connection.

Answer (score 1):

Cyberduck! Available for Windows (as well as OSX) and allows as many uploads as you connection can handle - and even multiple connections to the same host.

https://cyberduck.io

Comment: Great, thanks, and it has a retry option as well http://i.stack.imgur.com/nh6Ch.png

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: I can't try at the moment, but the spinner value in the "Transfers" window goes up to 9 only. Is that the maximum connection count?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I haven't tested it (I encountered some hard drive issue on the server where I wanted to use Cyberduck)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I tested too, 9 indeed this seems to be the max.